# Using NLog how can I make my modules log to their own unique log file

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I'm trying to change an application so that when it creates an instance of a module (a class defined in another assembly) it can provide the necessary information to the module so that it can create it's own logger based off the configuration of the service application loading it.

When I first started working on this the most logical solution to me was to create a log configuration file with a custom parameter that is used to determine the file name.

```
<variable name="module" value="Service"/>

<targets>
   <target name="logFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}Logs/${var:module}.txt"
            layout="${time} ${uppercase:${level}} ${var:module} ${logger} ${message}" />
</targets>
```

Then I store the LoggingConfiguration so every time a module is loaded I create a new LogFactory based off of the configuration, change the custom variable value, and inject it as a dependency on the module for it to use for creating its own loggers.

The problem I keep encountering, even when I write a complex method to attempt to clone the LoggingConfiguration, is it always results in everything, service included, logging to the specifications of the last LogFactory created.

I feel like I'm missing something and could really use some help either figuring out how I can make this solution work or any suggestions for a better idea of how I might achieve the same goal of a unique log file per module.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make use of the Logger-name ?

```
<targets>
   <target name="ModulesTarget" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}Logs/${logger:shortname=true}.txt" />
</targets>
<rules>
   <logger name="Modules.*" target="ModulesTarget"/>
</rules>
```

Then create the module logger like this:

```
var moduleLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Modules.MyModuleName");
```

Comment: I was aware that you could declare loggers based on name but I was unaware that you could set the filename to say the short type name.  I could probably make this work but it's going to limit the range of what I want to do with it.  I was really hoping I could just pass say an ILogFactory instance that would be passed around the module such that each class within the module can create it's own named logger such that they all log to the same file but the originating class or type can be distinguished.  Thank you for your suggestion and I'll update the post if I go that route.

Comment: I wasn't successful using the target="ModulesTarget". Problem solved when I used writeTo="ModulesTarget". Other than that, nice solution. Using it now.

Answer (score 1):

You could also provide a common interface for all modules. This interface also includes the ability acquire a custom Logger-object that wraps an NLog Logger.

The custom Logger-object then injects the module name into `LogEventInfo.Properties`. Maybe extracted from:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Name
```

Then you can use `${event-properties:item=ModuleName}` in the filename.

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 0):

You could also create an isolated `LogFactory` for each module:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging

Comment: Thanks for you input and I think I missed that page on the wiki.  I haven't tried it in my primary project yet but it worked in a test project I created.  The problem I ran into initially with it is the fact that I can't seem to reuse the XmlLoggingConfiguration as changes to it propagates across all LogFactories created with it even when I try to clone it by copying all of its targets and rules to a new instance so the solution I suspect in this case is to keep reloading it from a file which feels 'dirty' to me but may still be the best solution.